# Need help identifying - Alternate history - Spanish Armada wins over English

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, alternate-history

Can somebody help me identify this story which I read in the 1980s(?).

What I remember is that in 1588 the Spanish Armada was **not** destroyed on its way to battle the English fleet and the English were defeated. This leads to a present 20th century in which The Spanish are the dominant culture. Technology has developed differently, with time travel but no electric light nor automobiles.

Comment: At first I thought it might be [Pavane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pavane_(novel)) but the time-travel thing is a bit of a clincher

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is "[Times Without Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Times_Without_Number)" by John Brunner.

- **The Armada was successful**

  > The book's plot takes place in the years 1988–1989 in a timeline where
  >   the Spanish Armada under the command of the Duke of Parma successfully
  >   invaded England in 1588. This success was especially due to Parma's
  >   second-in-command, the Earl of Barton – the illegitimate son of a
  >   Catholic Scottish nobleman, who entered the service of Spain and
  >   turned out to be one of the great military talents of history (at the
  >   end of the book it is explained why our history knows no such person).
- **Time travel technology is present in an otherwise backward society**

  > Meanwhile, in Europe the Habsburg Monarchy transformed itself into the
  >   powerful "Confederacy of the East", ruling the whole of central and
  >   eastern Europe and becoming the long-lasting rival of the
  >   Londres-based Western Empire. In 1892, an Italian named Boromeo
  >   discovered the secret of time-travel, though otherwise the overall
  >   level of technology remained not much higher than it was in the 16th
  >   Century, with people travelling primarily on horseback and cities lit
  >   by open fires. in principle, time travel could have been used as a
  >   means of instantaneous travel, but that would have involved the
  >   traveller being in two places at the same time, at least for a split
  >   second; fearing a time paradox, such use of the device was strictly
  >   forbidden.

[image]

Comment: @nmgsantiago - [Always a pleasure :-)](https://www.mememaker.net/static/images/memes/3978516.jpg)